# Tensorboard Unble to get first event timestamp for run

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to visualize a training session I trained in a remote server. I used scp to copy the file in my local iMac. I tried to visualize the data by running tensorboard. It runs the tensorboard site but I can't get the visualization. Every chart has a single dot at zero. I get this warning on the terminal.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Unable to get first event timestamp for run 
470_313_0.0001_2500_200/train
WARNING:tensorflow:Unable to get first event timestamp for run 
470_313_0.0001_2500_200/train
WARNING:tensorflow:Unable to get first event timestamp for run 
470_313_0.0001_2500_200/val
WARNING:tensorflow:Unable to get first event timestamp for run 
470_313_0.0001_2500_50/train
WARNING:tensorflow:Unable to get first event timestamp for run 
470_313_0.0001_2500_50/val
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: It sounds like there may be something wrong with your events files. Please file an issue at github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard, and attach your event file to the issue. We'll take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem. There are 2 solutions to it -

- Delete all past tfevents files from the directory and keep the latest one (temporary solution).
- Create a new directory for building your logs (permanent solution).

In given below picture, first I build logs in directory 2 which resulted in same error/warnings. Later I changed the directory to 3 and build logs there and tensorboard ran successfully.
[image: Problem and its solution]

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem (with a TensorFlow 1.4 trainer running in the cloud with Google Cloud ML Engine).

Explicitly closing `tf.summary.FileWriter`s with `close()` solved it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the directory names for the runs were too long. After I manually renamed them, the problem is solved.