# Tensorboard can not find the timestamp of the event

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I can open the website which tensorboard shows me, but there is no data in it, and the cmd says that it can not find the first timestamp of the event.

I type something like this

./tensorboard --logdir=G:/final/log_1

I try many times on win7 and win10 and I am sure that the path is right, but there are no data in that website.

Part of my code

```
with tf.name_scope('input_layer'):
    xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 9],name="x_input")
    ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 1],name="y_input")
```

My code for creating the event file, it will create a file named log_1, and the event files will be in that file

```
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(r'log_1/',sess.graph)
writer.close()
```

I expect the website can show me the graph, however, it showed nothing

Comment: what is your python version? and have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831317/tensorboard-unble-to-get-first-event-timestamp-for-run?

Comment: Thanks for you comment! My python version is 3.5, I have added the tf.summary.FileWriter in my code, and now it come up an error that 'you must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_layer/x_input' with dtype float and shape [1,9]', and now I am trying to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

1) Firstly, if you are running it on an editor like Jupyter try restarting the kernel.

2) Secondly, I don't know your whole code but one thing you have to do is

`merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
 summary = sess.run(merged)
 writer.add_summary(summary, index)`

One problem with your code can be that you are creating all the summary variables but you are not actually adding it to the writer. So before you close it use the above `add_summary` function. I had the same problem recently and all of the above solved it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I did forgotten to add it to the writer, but after adding the code above, I got this 'You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_layer/x_input' with dtype float and shape [1,9]'. And then I was advised to add tf.reset_default_graph, but I got the error that 'list index out of range',did you meet similar problems?

Comment: Can you exactly write on what does it give you list index out of range? It would be better if you could show me that line of the code, where it gives you an error.